# my login frame cannot link to my other frame

Tags: java, frame, login-control

my login page exits but cannot redirect to the specified frame. i have researched it but still not working. it just exits but does not redirect.
this is the part of the code for my login. They are all in the same package

```
 String use=user.getText();
       String ps=password.getText();
       if(e.getSource()==log){
         if((use.contains("emma"))&& (ps.contains("nana")))
        {   

       Stud now=new Stud();

        now.setVisible(true); 
        user.setText("");
        pass.setText("");

        // new   Stud ().setVisible(true);
           System.exit(0);
        }
         else{

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Inputs, PROVIDE PROPER CREDENTIALS", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove "System.exit(0);" from your code. this code terminating running Java virtual machine(JVM).

Comment: it worked. but how can i make the login page disappear after redirection